# how to know watch(Android Wearable device) facing up or down on the wrist?

Tags: android, wear-os

i am developing an app where if watch facing up then i have to unlock the screen and if watch facing down i have to lock the screen. I am not able to find out how to get watch facing up or down on the wrist.

Comment: Look into accelerometer instrument data. Also, is this feature not baked into Android Wear already? My LG G watch R wakes up when I snap my wrist to look at the time.

Comment: @MeetTitan thanx for ur suggestion! No that features is not there. Could you please telll me any example code of this.

Comment: Start by taking a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html.